# C# - Scripting - File still being used

Tags: c#

I'm using the *CodeDomProvider* class to compile my scripts in a certain application I'm developing. Those are the 3 methods I'm using.

```
public static void CompileNpcScripts(bool pLoadCompiledScripts)
    {
        Dictionary<string, DateTime> compiledScripts = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

        foreach (var script in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("..\\DataSvr\\Script\\Compiled\\", "*.compiled"))
        {
            compiledScripts.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(script), System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(script));
        }

        List<string> needCompliation = new List<string>();
        foreach (var script in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("..\\DataSvr\\Script\\", "*.s"))
        {
            var shortname = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(script);
            if (!compiledScripts.ContainsKey(shortname) || compiledScripts[shortname] < System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(script))
            {
                needCompliation.Add(script);
            }
        }

        foreach (var script in needCompliation)
        {
            var shortname = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(script);

            _usableNpcScripts.Remove(shortname);

            CompilerResults results = CompileScript(ScriptType.Npc, script);
        }

        foreach (var script in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("..\\DataSvr\\Script\\Compiled\\", "*.compiled"))
        {
            var shortname = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(script);

            if (!_usableNpcScripts.ContainsKey(shortname))
            {
                _usableNpcScripts.Add(shortname, Assembly.LoadFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + script));
            }
        }

        if (pLoadCompiledScripts)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Assembly> script in _usableNpcScripts)
            {
                GameServer.NpcScripts.Add(script.Key, (INpcScript)ScriptingTools.FindInterface(script.Value, "INpcScript"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var script in needCompliation)
            {
                var shortname = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(script);

                if (GameServer.NpcScripts.ContainsKey(shortname))
                {
                    GameServer.NpcScripts[shortname] = (INpcScript)ScriptingTools.FindInterface(_usableNpcScripts[shortname], "INpcScript");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static CompilerResults CompileScript(ScriptType pType, string pSource)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_compiler == null)
            {
                _compiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
                _compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();

                _compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
                _compilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";
                // TODO: Should it be generated in memory?
                _compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = false;
                _compilerParams.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
                _compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
                _compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                { }
                int lol;
            }

            _compilerParams.OutputAssembly = "Scripts\\" + pType + "\\Compiled\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pSource) + ".compiled";
            var result = _compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile(_compilerParams, pSource);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(_compilerParams.OutputAssembly))
            {
                System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime(_compilerParams.OutputAssembly, System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(pSource));
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Stil being used by the user.
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static object FindInterface(Assembly pDLL, string pInterface)
    {
        foreach (Type type in pDLL.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.GetInterface(pInterface, true) != null)
                return pDLL.CreateInstance(type.FullName);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The boolean "pLoadCompiledScripts" is to tell the program if the script should be *reloaded* or *inserted*. GameServer's NpcScripts dictionairy is just a collection of the interface INpcScript.

Now. On the initla load I call the following: CompileNpcScripts(true), so it will check for the files that need compliation, will recompile them and then will load all of them to the dictionairy. I also have a FileWatcher class which watches the Script folder for changes. Once the event is raised, I call CompileNpcScripts(false), so it will reload existing scripts. However, the CompileScript method returns null because the file "[name].compiled" is being used by another process. Why is it like so an dhow can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: TL;DR; Random guess - "compiled" is name of the assembly and you `Load` that assembly - so without unloading the assembly via appDomain unload you'll not be able to overwrite the file of that assembly.

Comment: `_compiler` is an `IDisposable` resource, so you should be calling `.Dispose()` on it (or wrapping it its usage in `using`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be one of two things.

First, check your `FileWatcher` class and make sure it's not holding onto any of the files it's watching (like accessing the last modified date property or whatever the case may be).

Secondly, the compiler might still be holding onto the scripts after it gets down compiling them. I would try and dispose of the compiler and rebuild it each time I went to recompile the scripts.